# BeautifulSoup getting attribute value not working

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have code to extract an attribute value but it is not getting all of them only if i specifically go into one. I am confused as to what is incorrect.

```
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/market-news'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

news = soup.find(name="ul", attrs={'class':"item-list",'id':'latest-news-list'})
root = 'https://seekingalpha.com'

#id_list = [i['id'] for i in news.find_all(name='li', attrs={'class':'item'})]
heading_list = [i.text for i in news.find_all('a')]
#url_list = [root+i['href'] for i in news.find_all('a')]
datehtml = news.find_all(name='li', attrs={'class':'item'})
date_list = [news.find_all(name='li', attrs={'class':'item'})[i] for i in range(len(datehtml))]
#date_list2 = [i.split()[0] for i in date_list]
#id_list2 = [i.split('-')[2] for i in id_list]

date_list[1]['data-last-date'] # works
[i['data-last-date'] for i in date_list] #error
```

[image: code erros]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit messy, that's for starters. Other than that, why don't you just grab all `li` tags with class `item` and extract the attribute value?

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/market-news'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser').find_all("li", {"class", "item"})
print([l.get("data-last-date") for l in soup])
```

Output:

```
['2020-11-10 11:43:36 -0500', '2020-11-10 11:38:12 -0500', None, '2020-11-10 11:37:37 -0500', '2020-11-10 11:35:56 -0500', '2020-11-10 11:34:53 -0500', '2020-11-10 11:16:19 -0500', '2020-11-10 11:13:32 -0500', '2020-11-10 11:12:55 -0500', '2020-11-10 11:04:01 -0500', '2020-11-10 11:00:25 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:52:45 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:51:07 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:49:43 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:45:27 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:45:01 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:40:28 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:35:38 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:29:40 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:28:35 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:25:52 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:25:31 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:22:57 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:20:58 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:18:00 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:15:18 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:11:18 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:04:29 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:03:10 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:02:43 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:01:56 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:01:42 -0500', '2020-11-10 10:00:48 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:58:09 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:57:17 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:56:11 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:55:39 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:54:42 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:50:00 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:47:51 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:47:29 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:47:13 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:46:59 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:46:12 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:40:10 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:37:15 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:37:00 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:35:46 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:35:46 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:34:25 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:31:43 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:29:51 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:27:39 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:27:24 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:21:19 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:19:07 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:18:40 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:17:57 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:17:53 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:16:24 -0500', '2020-11-10 09:15:46 -0500']
```